# Gesture event to scroll page

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad, safari, gesture

I have a page which has a long grid/table data...I am testing it on iPad Safari.

Now i want to be able to scroll through the entire page using some kind of gesture..
I know you might be thinking that I should be able to scroll automatically using 1-finger. However, i am using 1-finger for dragging the grid items..

So need some other way to be able to scroll through the page..Can i use some kind of gesturestart events to be able to scroll through the page. Any example would be really great..

Thank you.

Comment: I agree with ArtWorkAD, you may add some margins to both sides of your grid so that users can use that to scroll.

Comment: Well..i'll be making an iPad optimized app separately where the design/spacing itself will take care of this issue...But as of now, I am using the same desktop app on the iPad..So i want to know how this can be done ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can have a look on that page which explain a lot on things about touch / gesture events :

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html

Comment: Well i already had a look at that ref before asking the question here...I am looking for a way to override the behavior for 2-finger move to have the scrolling behavior..

Comment: By setting overflow: auto; you have 2 fingers scroll. Try to reduce the height of the scroller element

Comment: I even tried doing that..But very strangely, even that did not work..Not sure if that behavior is getting overridden somewhere in my code..

Comment: @ChristopheCVB let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1793/discussion-between-hmthr-and-christophecvb)